# How to debug unexpected symbol in R

Tags: r

I know that is really simple. I'm trying to calculate:

```
-2ˆ2 -(2.6)ˆ2 * (1/2)
```

```
Error: unexpected input in "-2�"
```

Comment: IT could be a copy error from some pdf where the `^` may be a different symbol that got copied

Comment: Agree with @akrun. R is particularly finicky when it comes to non-ASCII characters (whereas some other languages deal with them just fine). Other examples include "smart quotes" (that R itself generates!), some greater-than/less-than symbols, wide-hyphens, etc. Because of this, you need to be careful when copying code from webpages or word documents.

Comment: You tried to use `ˆ` which is the diacritical mark that is used to accent letter. You need `^` which is caret.

Answer (score 2):

When I replace the `ˆ` with `^` it works on my system.